# Google Maps and Contact Form 7 Alignment

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-maps, contact-form-7

I am trying to align google maps to the right side of contact form 7 in wordpress. However, I can not get the alignment correct. It keeps messing up the contact form when I float the google maps over.

This image is what I would like to achieve.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4EqD.jpg

This is what I am currently getting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dvC5.jpg

This is the code that has been used.

```html
<div style="float:left;width:200px;">
[contact-form-7 id="16" title="Contact form 1"]
</div>
<div style="float:right;width:425px;">
[wpgmza id="1"]
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using flex like this :

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
  <div style="width:200px;">
    [contact-form-7 id="16" title="Contact form 1"]
  </div>
  <div style="flex:1;">
    [wpgmza id="1"]
  </div>
```